# How to make http request in nodejs to url which is not linked to DNS but registered in hosts file?

Tags: node.js, dns, httprequest, hosts

I am working on remote sandbox with ip **190.34.24.56** (not real ip, just for example)

Hosts file contains this string:

```
190.34.24.56 web.sandbox.com
```

I have access to url **web.sandbox.com** from browser, but when try to send http request I get an error: **ENOTFOUND** (domain name not found).

How to send http request from nodejs to url which not have dns record?
(I can't enter to sandbox using 190.34.24.56, because there is host-server works which determine incoming url and redirects request to other port, so I can use only **web.sandbox.com**)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't actually tried this, but you could try passing in the domain header along with your request:

```
Host: yourhostname.com
```

See full list of HTTP headers: [List of HTTP header fields](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields)

Comment: Thanks, problem resolved. Actual problem was incorrect using of Host http header, I used full path like 'web.sandbox.com/blabla', but need to use like this {host : 'web.sandbox.com', path : 'blabla'}